# Request textDocument/codeAction failed. Message: Internal error, please look at the server's logs. Code: -32603 vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

```
Request textDocument/codeAction failed.
  Message: Internal error, please look at the server's logs.
  Code: -32603
```

eveytime when i click README.md file, I always cathch this error at the terminal
[image]

i have checked the Markdown server, there was no something wrong.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: In my case, the problem was one of the Markdown processor Quarto. I disabled it for my workspace and my problem was solved. Do you have this kind of extension in your VSCode?

Answer (score 3):

I just had the same error and was caused by this extension "LanguageTool Linter". After uninstalling it (disable would probably work also) it stopped giving errors.

Answer (score 0):

Removing `adamvoss.vscode-languagetool` extension fixed the problem in my case